# Java with mockito fails

Tags: java, mockito

I have following method in my service to mock AWS sqs

```
@Override
public Message recieveMessage(String queueUrl) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(queueUrl);
    ReceiveMessageRequest request = new ReceiveMessageRequest().withQueueUrl(queueUrl).withMaxNumberOfMessages(1);
    ReceiveMessageResult receiveMessageResult = this.sqsClient.receiveMessage(request);
    // As per the spec, we need to return only one message.
    return receiveMessageResult.getMessages().get(0);
}

@Override
public int getMessageCount(String queueUrl) {
    GetQueueAttributesResult queueAttributes = sqsClient.getQueueAttributes(queueUrl, Arrays.asList("ApproximateNumberOfMessages"));
    return Integer.valueOf(queueAttributes.getAttributes().get("ApproximateNumberOfMessages"));
}
```

and following are my test cases for these methods using mockito are failing with NPE.

```
@Test
public void testRecieveMessage() {

    Message message = new Message();
    message.setBody("Message Body");

    List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();
    messages.add(message);

    ReceiveMessageResult result = new ReceiveMessageResult();
    result.setMessages(messages);

    when(mock(ReceiveMessageResult.class).getMessages()).thenReturn(messages);
    when(mock(List.class).get(0)).thenReturn(message);
    when(this.amazonSQSClient.receiveMessage(mock(ReceiveMessageRequest.class))).thenReturn(result);

    this.amazonQueueService.recieveMessage(anyString());
    verify(this.amazonSQSClient, times(1)).receiveMessage(mock(ReceiveMessageRequest.class));
    //Assert.assertNotNull(msg);
}
```

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.queue.service.impl.AmazonSQSService.recieveMessage(AmazonSQSService.java:46)
    at com.example.AmazonSQSServiceTest.testRecieveMessage(AmazonSQSServiceTest.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

```
@Test
public void testMessageCount() {
    GetQueueAttributesResult result = new GetQueueAttributesResult();
    result.addAttributesEntry("ApproximateNumberOfMessages", "10");
    List<String> attrs = Arrays.asList("ApproximateNumberOfMessages");
    when(this.amazonSQSClient.getQueueAttributes(anyString(), eq(attrs))).thenReturn(result);
    this.amazonQueueService.getMessageCount(anyString());
}
```

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
2 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
-> at com.example.AmazonSQSServiceTest.testMessageCount(AmazonSQSServiceTest.java:96)

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.

```
at com.example.queue.service.impl.AmazonSQSService.getMessageCount(AmazonSQSService.java:58)
at com.example.AmazonSQSServiceTest.testMessageCount(AmazonSQSServiceTest.java:96)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what your code does:

```
ReceiveMessageRequest request = new ReceiveMessageRequest().withQueueUrl(queueUrl).withMaxNumberOfMessages(1);
ReceiveMessageResult receiveMessageResult = this.sqsClient.receiveMessage(request);
```

So it creates a new request, and passes ths new request to `sqsClient.receiveMessage()`.

Here's how you test that:

```
when(this.amazonSQSClient.receiveMessage(mock(ReceiveMessageRequest.class))).thenReturn(result);
```

So your test tells th mock client to return `result` when `receiveMessage()` is called with a mock ReceiveMessageRequest.

So that can't work. The mock ReceiveMessageRequest is not equal to the new request used in the code. You need to do something like

```
when(this.amazonSQSClient.receiveMessage(any(ReceiveMessageRequest.class))).thenReturn(result);
```

So that, whetever the request passed to receiveMessage, the mock client returns the result.

Regarding your second question:

```
this.amazonQueueService.getMessageCount(anyString());
```

doesn't make sense. You need to call your method with a real, given string.